# LiveSearch PHP, JavaScript and use in multiple fields

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, livesearch

I am new to JavaScript and have been working on a live search with PHP, Ajax, Javascript, and mysql.

It works great with the first ID field but I have 8 total input fields that I need to work with it, I have tried to edit the getElementById but the search did not work.

How should I edit the JavaScript to allow for the live search to be used on each of 8 input fields and still deliver the chosen search item as the field value?

JavaScript:

```
function liveSearch()
{
var url = "livesearch.php";
var s = document.getElementById('med1').value;
var params = "&s="+s;
http.open("POST", url, true);

http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status != 200) {
document.getElementById('searchResults1').innerHTML='<li>Loading...</li>';
}
if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
document.getElementById('searchResults1').innerHTML = http.responseText; 
} 
}
http.send(params);
}

function sendToSearch(str){
document.getElementById('med1').value = str;
document.getElementById('searchResults1').innerHTML = "";
}
```

PHP:

```
$s = $_REQUEST["s"];
$output = "";
$s = str_replace(" ", "%", $s);
$query = "SELECT * FROM drug_list WHERE NAME LIKE '%" . $s . "%' or COMMON_NAME LIKE '%" . $s."%' or ALIAS LIKE '%" . $s . "%' LIMIT 10";
$squery = mysql_query($query);
if((mysql_num_rows($squery) != 0) && ($s != "")){
while($sLookup = mysql_fetch_array($squery)){
$displayName = $sLookup["COMMON_NAME"];
$product_name = $sLookup['NAME'];
$dose = $sLookup["DOSAGE"];
$units = $sLookup["UNITS"];
$output .= '<li onclick="sendToSearch(\''.$product_name.' (' . $displayName .') '.$dose.' '.$units. '\')">'.$product_name.' (' . $displayName .') '.$dose.' '.$units.'</li>';
}
}   

echo $output;
```

HTML Form (partial - goes out to 8 medications with ID='med(n)'):

```
<td size='20'>Medication 1</td><td><input type='text' name='med1' id='med1' size='40' title='i.e.-Metoprolol 50 mg twice a day' onkeyup='liveSearch()' /></td><td size='40'><input type='text' name='med1_reason' size='40' title='i.e.-Highblood Pressure' /></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan='3' align='left'><span style='color:blue; cursor:pointer'><ul id="searchResults1"></ul></span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td size='20'>Medication 2</td><td><input type='text' name='med2' id='med2' size='40' title='i.e.-Metoprolol 50 mg twice a day' onkeyup='liveSearch()' /></td><td size='40'><input type='text' name='med2_reason' size='40' title='i.e.-Highblood Pressure' /></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan='3' align='left'><span style='color:blue; cursor:pointer'><ul id="searchResults2"></ul></span></td></tr>
<tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happend because you use explicitely the object with id "med1". You have to modify your code like this:

Javascript:

```
function liveSearch(obj, no) { 
    var url = "livesearch.php"; 
    var s = obj.value; 
    var params = "&s="+s+"&no=" + no; 
    http.open("POST", url, true); 

    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length); 
    http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close"); 

    http.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status != 200) { 
            document.getElementById('searchResults' + no).innerHTML='<li>Loading...</li>'; 
        } 
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) { 
            document.getElementById('searchResults' + no).innerHTML = http.responseText;  
        }  
    } 
    http.send(params); 
} 

function sendToSearch(str, no){ 
    document.getElementById('med' + no).value = str; 
    document.getElementById('searchResults' + no).innerHTML = ""; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<td size='20'>Medication 1</td><td><input type='text' name='med1' id='med1' size='40' title='i.e.-Metoprolol 50 mg twice a day' onkeyup='liveSearch(this,1)' /></td><td size='40'><input type='text' name='med1_reason' size='40' title='i.e.-Highblood Pressure' /></td> 
</tr> 
<tr><td colspan='3' align='left'><span style='color:blue; cursor:pointer'><ul id="searchResults1"></ul></span></td></tr> 
<tr> 
<td size='20'>Medication 2</td><td><input type='text' name='med2' id='med2' size='40' title='i.e.-Metoprolol 50 mg twice a day' onkeyup='liveSearch(this,2)' /></td><td size='40'><input type='text' name='med2_reason' size='40' title='i.e.-Highblood Pressure' /></td> 
</tr> 
<tr><td colspan='3' align='left'><span style='color:blue; cursor:pointer'><ul id="searchResults2"></ul></span></td></tr> 
<tr>
```

PHP:

```
$s = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["s"]); 
$output = ""; 
$s = str_replace(" ", "%", $s); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM drug_list WHERE NAME LIKE '%" . $s . "%' or COMMON_NAME LIKE '%" . $s."%' or ALIAS LIKE '%" . $s . "%' LIMIT 10"; 
$squery = mysql_query($query);

if((mysql_num_rows($squery) != 0) && ($s != "")){ 
    while($sLookup = mysql_fetch_array($squery)){ 
        $displayName = $sLookup["COMMON_NAME"]; 
        $product_name = $sLookup['NAME']; 
        $dose = $sLookup["DOSAGE"]; 
        $units = $sLookup["UNITS"]; 
        $output .= '<li onclick="sendToSearch(\''.$product_name.' (' . $displayName .') '.$dose.' '.$units. '\',' . $_REQUEST['no'] . ')">'.$product_name.' (' . $displayName .') '.$dose.' '.$units.'</li>'; 
    } 
}    

echo $output;
```

I think this should work for you, good luck!

Comment: Have tried your code but i get an error. please help. can i have a jsfiddle of that sir?